# Script: Match and delete lines with specific pattern

Tags: python, bash, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to create a master wordlist to test a specific type of routers in my lab. I already know what specific pattern the passwords follows. I have created a first wordlist ("raw_wordlist.txt") file using the character set [A-F 0-9] with crunch,

```
crunch  8 8 ABCDEF0123456789 -d 3 -o raw_wordlist.txt
```

witch resulted in a *4289986800* lines file called "raw_wordlist.txt".

Now I am trying to further narrow down the the wordlist for fiewer lines.

*here is a snippet:*

```
193B068D
B9AB0685
B9AB068F
A9AAA69A
B98B069B
B9AB069C
B9AB069D
B9A2069E
B9AB069F
```

Here is what I am trying to achieve.

- delete all lines starting with 3 numeric characters (as in 193B068D)
- delete all lines ending with 3 numeric characters (as in B9AB0685)
- delete all lines containing more than 4 numeric values (as in B98B069B or B9A2069E)
- delete all lines containing more than 4 values of the same character [A-F] (as in A9AAA69A)

There are currently no options in crunch to do this automatically, so my only option was to created a base wordlist first and then narrow down with a script afterwards.

I have tried solutions like

```
sed -e '/^[0-9]{3}/d' -e '/[0-9]{3}$/d' raw_wordlist.txt > hexwordlist.txt
```

witch can solve the leading and tailing digit issue but I am still to figure out how to eliminate based on caracter count.

I don't know how I could implement this using something like sed or grep or awk, or perhaps using pypthon? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does your file include line numbers like in your example?

Comment: No, that was just to reference the lines in the topic.

Comment: @EdMorton I just signed up to the website and haven't got the chance to learn how everything is supposed to work. I guess I had to show what I had tried so far. I am a Network Admin trying to get into Security and scripting. Sorry if I made a wrong impression.

Comment: Sure, will do. Thanks for the guideline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with ***sed*** solution with *BRE* (basic regex expression):

```
sed '/^[0-9]\{3\}\|[0-9]\{3\}$\|[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*\|\([A-F]\).*\1.*\1.*\1.*\1.*/d' file
```

The output (for your current input fragment):

```
B9AB068F
B9AB069C
B9AB069D
B9AB069F
```

---

- the whole expression is an alternate group
- `^[0-9]{3}` - matches the entry starting with 3 digits
- `[0-9]$` - matches the entry ending with 3 digits
- `[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*` - matches the entry containing at least 5 digits (more than 4)
- `([A-F]).*\1.*\1.*\1.*\1.*` - matches the entry containing at least 5 same 
  letters `[A-F]` (more than 4)
- `d` - *sed* subcommand to delete matched lines

---

The alternative ***sed*** approach (with *ERE*) would look like below:

```
sed -E '/^[0-9]{3}|[0-9]{3}$|([0-9].*){5}|([A-F])(.*\2){4}/d' file
```

Comment: - [0-9]{3} - matches the entry ending with 3 digits. I think you mean [0-9]{3}$

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest suggest to add `grep -vE '^[0-9]{3}|[0-9]{3}$|([0-9].*){5}|([A-F])(.*\2){4}' file` also as solution.. I will wager it will be faster than `sed` and OP mentions huge input file...

Comment: @Sundeep, no need to wager for `grep` - it's permanently faster for pattern matching. I just decided not to add grep approach as @Cyrus had added it previously (I don't know why he had deleted his answer) http://stackoverflow.com/a/44087932/3185459

Answer (score 0):

Adding a solution not relying on regex. Should be fairly easy to expand by adding new functions to the `matchers` list.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import collections

inputcontent = """193B068D
B9AB0685
B9AB068F
A9AAA69A
B98B069B
B9AB069C
B9AB069D
B9A2069E
B9AB069F
""".strip()

# Read inputcontent from standard input if you want, otherwise just copy into
# this string.

def starts_with_3_numeric(s):
    return all(c in "0123456789" for c in s[:3])

def ends_with_3_numeric(s):
    return all(c in "0123456789" for c in s[-3:])

def contains_4_numeric(s):
    return len([c for c in s if c in "0123456789"]) > 4

def contains_more_than_4_equal_chars(s):
    count = collections.Counter(s)
    return max(count[c] for c in s) > 4

matchers = [
    starts_with_3_numeric,
    ends_with_3_numeric,
    contains_4_numeric,
    contains_more_than_4_equal_chars,
]

filtered = [line.strip()
            for line in inputcontent.splitlines()
            if not any(matcher(line.strip()) for matcher in matchers)]

for outline in filtered:
    print outline
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW here's how you'd do it with GNU awk for patsplit() (or `FPAT`):

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^[0-9]{3}|[0-9]{3]+$/ { next }
gsub(/[0-9]/,"&") > 4  { next }
{
    delete cnt
    patsplit($0,tgt,/[A-F]/)
    for (i in tgt) {
        if ( ++cnt[tgt[i]] > 4 ) {
            next
        }
    }
}
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
B9AB068F
B9AB069C
B9AB069D
B9AB069F
```

It takes more code than sed because, unlike sed, awk doesn't support backreferences in a regexp.